# Redis queue in node.js for database inserts

Tags: node.js, database, performance, redis

I need some help on figure out what best practice would be in case when you need to insert a lot of data for each request when using node, redis and lets say MySQL/MongoDB.

How would you set up a queue to handle each request like this:

- The user request a url within my app, ie /route/insert-data
- The server handles the request, adds it to a Redis queue, and sends back status 200 to the user
- With some kind of interval the application checks if there is anything in the redis queue, if so, it will pick the oldest one, insert it to the database, and then remove the key from redis

What would be the best approach here? I'm currently have a express app setup.

Thanks!

Comment: have you found any direction about this? am interested too

Comment: @medBouzid no, not yet. Maybe it is to broad?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution, but if someone was looking.
The pseudocode would be :

1. Find the nearest (rounded upward) timestamp second to your interval (say every 5 seconds)
2. Use that timestamp as a key for redis
3. use redis append to append values to that key
4. periodically check (every second) for the last divisible redis key using getdel (get, then delete, to be more performant).

This can be more performant, but it's just for you to understand the easiest flow to be (redis would be the redis client, assuming you are using the library : https://github.com/redis/node-redis )

```js
function findNearestTimestamp() {
  var currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Get the current time in seconds
  var remainder = currentTime % 5; // Calculate the remainder

  if (remainder === 0) {
    return currentTime; // Current time is already divisible by 5 seconds
  } else {
    var nearestTimestamp = currentTime + (5 - remainder); // Calculate the nearest timestamp
    return nearestTimestamp;
  }
}
const sql_values = "('value1', 'value2', 'value3'),";
const redis_key = findNearestTimestamp(5);
redis.append(redis_key,sql_values)
```

And you can periodically check for the keys in a simple way such as

```js
    function findLastDivisibleTimestamp(seconds) {
      var currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Get the current time in seconds
      var remainder = currentTime % seconds; // Calculate the remainder

      var lastDivisibleTimestamp = currentTime - remainder; // Subtract the remainder

      return lastDivisibleTimestamp;
    }

setTimeout(()=> {

    const last_redis_key = findLastDivisibleTimestamp(5)
    const stored_value =  redis.getdel(last_redis_key) 
    const cleaned_value = stored_value ? str.slice(0,-1) : null

    if (!cleaned_value) {
        //run query here by appending values to sql insert such as 
        const query = `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
    VALUES ${values}`
    }
}), 1 * 1000)
```

Due note, you will need to add more code to ensure that on cases of database failure, you catch it, retry it, append to the next one, dump it or otherwise.